# login Component are not Working Properly on react js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tailwind-css

**in the Bellow code Where is the Error **

[Server Are Running Fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk14W.png)

```js
>         import React, { useEffect } from "react";
>         import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
>         import logo from '../App/asset/logo.webp'
> 
>         const Login = () => {
> 
> 
>           const [email, setEmail] = React.useState('');
>           const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');
>           const navigate = useNavigate();
> 
>           useEffect(() => {
>             const auth = localStorage.getItem('user');
>             if (auth) {
>               navigate("/dashboard")
>             }
>           }, [])
> 
>           const handleLogin = async () => {
>             let result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
>               method: 'post',
>               body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
>               headers: {
>                 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>               }
>             });
>             result = await result.json();
>             console.log(result)
>             if (result.auth) {
>               localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(result.user));
>               localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(result.auth));
>               navigate("/dashboard")
>             } else {
>               alert("Please enter connect details")
>             }
>           }
> 
> 
>           return (
>             <div className="bg-white dark:bg-secoundery">
>               <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">
>                 <div className="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow-2xl dark:border md:mt-0 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800
> dark:border-gray-700">
>                   <div className="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
>                     <div className="text-center mb-20">
>                       <img className="mx-auto w-48 " src={logo} alt="logo" />
>                     </div>
>                     <form className="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="#">
>                       <div className="relative mb-8">
>                         <input onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} id="email" name="email"
> type="text" className="w-full h-10 text-secoundery
> placeholder-transparent border-b-2 border-gray-300 peer
> focus:outline-none focus:border-primary" placeholder="john@doe.com"
> required />
>                         <label htmlFor="email" className="absolute left-0 -top-3.5 font-semibold text-secoundery text-sm transition-all
> peer-placeholder-shown:text-base
> peer-placeholder-shown:text-secoundery peer-placeholder-shown:top-2
> peer-focus:-top-3.5 peer-focus:text-gray-800 peer-focus:text-sm">Email
>                           address</label>
>                       </div>
>                       <div className="relative mb-8">
>                         <input onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} id="email" name="email"
> type="text" className="w-full h-10 text-secoundery
> placeholder-transparent border-b-2 border-gray-300 peer
> focus:outline-none focus:border-primary" placeholder="••••••••"
> required />
>                         <label htmlFor="email" className="absolute left-0 font-semibold -top-3.5 text-secoundery text-sm transition-all
> peer-placeholder-shown:text-base
> peer-placeholder-shown:text-secoundery peer-placeholder-shown:top-2
> peer-focus:-top-3.5 peer-focus:text-gray-800 peer-focus:text-sm">
>                           Password</label>
>                       </div>
>                       <div className="grid justify-items-center">
>                         <button onClick={handleLogin} type="submit" className=" w-2/4 text-white bg-primary hover:bg-secoundery
> focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary font-medium
> rounded-lg text-[18px] px-5 py-4 text-center dark:bg-primary
> dark:hover:bg-primary dark:focus:ring-primary">Login</button>
>                       </div>
>                     </form>
>                   </div>
>                 </div>
>               </div>
>             </div>
> 
>           )
>         }
> 
>         export default Login;
```

Comment: What error exactly? What is happening?

Comment: When Click on login Button Its Don't send any data on Consol log and not navigate to the Dashboard screen Component @KonradLinkowski

Answer (score 0):

1. This function should be assigned to `onSubmit` event on the `form` element
2. You have to use `preventDefault` or the page will reload

Comment: its Not Working